# Can you help me to understand the mode XCBC of authenticated-encryption?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, authenticated-encryption

[image]

I read: "$Z_0$ serves as an initial vector for CBC-like encryption, R is used to post-whitening each ciphertext block $C_i$ by $i ∗ R$".

but I don't understand what is the "post-whitening". Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_whitening) that key whitening increases security:

> In cryptography, key whitening is a technique intended to increase the security of an iterated block cipher. It consists of steps that combine the data with portions of the key.
>
> The most common form of key whitening is **xor-encrypt-xor** -- using a simple XOR before the first round and after the last round of encryption.
>
> The first block cipher to use a form of key whitening is DES-X, which simply uses two extra 64-bit keys for whitening, beyond the normal 56-bit key of DES. This is intended to increase the complexity of a brute force attack, increasing the effective size of the key without major changes in the algorithm. DES-X's inventor, Ron Rivest, named the technique whitening.
> In cryptography, key whitening is a technique intended to increase the security of an iterated block cipher. It consists of steps that combine the data with portions of the key (most commonly using a simple XOR) before the first round and after the last round of encryption.

The "post-whitening" consists into applying the whitening **after** the encryption function: **encrypt-xor**.